# How to make code execution pause until it is told to continue? Is it possible without using threads?

Tags: block, execution

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to what the Message Box that asks for confirmation in windows does. When the Message box is displayed the code that invoked it is blocked until the user clicks "Yes" or "No".
I want to do the same but the message box not flexible enough.

I'm developing a simple game and therefore I'm trying to avoid language-specific solution (a solution that works for only one programming language). This way I'll be able to port the game to different platforms like iphone, windows, mac ... etc without much change to code design.

To give a pseudo code example and assuming I have an array:

**for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

{**
    ...
    *Code to Show Message-box-like UI component.*  ==> Here the code is supposed to wait until user selects "Yes" or "NO" from the UI component.
**}**

I tried the following solution:

**bool userClickedYesOrNo = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){**
    ...
    *Code to Show Message-box-like UI component.*  ==> The code execution is not blocked
    **while (userClickedYesOrNo == false){**
         // when user clicks yes / no from the UI  then userClickedYesOrNo becomes true
    **}**
**}**

Unfortunately, in Windows, if I use a while loop then the UI is frozen and the user will not get a chance to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

Most code that doesn't use threads but wants to behave in an interactive way is based around events.

For instance, a standard '[display loop](http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch05lev1sec6.html)' in a Java SWT application sets up all the graphical components and then goes into an infinite loop. Similarly, JavaScript on a web page only has one thread, so must register handlers for [timer events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and so on to handle interaction in conjunction with ongoing background processing.

Inside the main loop the code checks to see if there is a pending job, and if so, the job is run.

In your game you can do something like this by having an 'update' job which updates the game state every 0.5s (say) and is triggered by a timer. When you pop up your dialog, you can set a flag which says 'pause' so that the update event just returns instead of doing any work. This allows the GUI events to continue to be handled by your display loop, and when the button is clicked the pause flag can be removed, allowing the game to continue.